# jquery ajax call not hitting c# webmethod. Hits page load though.

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I can't figure out why my Javascript ajax call won't hit my c# method. I build this up in my code behind.

```js
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", @"swal.withForm({
                        title: 'Database Credentials',
                        formFields: [{
                            id: 'server',
                            placeholder: 'Server Name'
                        }, {
                            id: 'username',
                            placeholder: 'User Name'
                        }, {
                            id: 'password',
                            placeholder: 'Password',
                            type: 'password'
                        }, {
                            id: 'databaseName',
                            placeholder: 'Database Name'
                        }],
                        html: true,
                        confirmButtonText: 'Update'
                    }, function(isConfirm) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.swalForm));
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: 'WebMethods.aspx/CheckCreateDatabase',
                            contentType: 'application / json; charset = utf - 8',
                            dataType: 'html',
                            data: JSON.stringify(this.swalForm),
                            success: function(data) {
                                swal('Success ' + data);
                            },
                            error: function(data, success, error) {
                                swal('Error ' + error);
                            }
                        });
                    });", true);
```

The console outputs this result for the json string, based on my inputs.

```
{"server":"dfd","username":"df","password":"dfd","databaseName":"dfd"}
```

My code behind

```
    public partial class WebMethods : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var a = "a";    
    }

[WebMethod]
    public static string CheckCreateDatabase(string server, string username, string password, string databaseName)
    {
        return "it worked";
    }
}
```

It will hit my break point in the page load event, but it won't hit it in the CheckCreateDatabase block.

I tried a bunch of different posts and still can't get it to hit that method. 
Does anyone see anything wrong or anything I can look into. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I copied the contenttype from a website and it had spaces in it. That was messing it up.